# only certain images not showing...why

Tags: html, image

I added some images and only the last two won't show up...maybe because it was naturally a smaller size?? I don't know...maybe someone here can help me....

Here is the part where i added them in my code

```
<div id="gallery">
            <ul>
                <li> <img src="images/studs/boss/thumbnails/boss0.jpg" class="mini" width="200" /> <img src="images/studs/boss/boss0.jpg" class="pic"  /> </li>
                <li> <img src="images/studs/boss/thumbnails/boss1.jpg" class="mini" width="200" /> <img src="images/studs/boss/boss1.jpg" class="pic"  />  </li>
                <li> <img src="images/studs/boss/thumbnails/boss2.jpg" class="mini" width="200" /> <img src="images/studs/boss/boss2.jpg" class="pic"  /> </li>
                <li> <img src="images/studs/boss/thumbnails/boss3.jpg" class="mini" width="200" /> <img src="images/studs/boss/boss3.jpg" class="pic"  /> </li>
                <li> <img src="images/studs/boss/thumbnails/boss4.jpg" class="mini" width="200" /> <img src="images/studs/boss/boss4.jpg" class="pic"  /> </li>
                <li> <img src="images/studs/boss/thumbnails/boss5.jpg" class="mini" width="200" /> <img src="images/studs/boss/boss5.jpg" class="pic"  /> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

the same thing you see online is the same thing I see when I access my site with local disk (my laptop where everything is stored)

i checked with chromes developer tools and I am getting "failed to load resource.." from the local disk.......like I am testing it on my computer before uploading...thats what I mean by local disk...if that is the right way to say it

this is my folder to show file structure...
[image: here is screenshot]

Comment: Use Firefox + Firebug, open the NET tab and you'll see whether you are getting the images or 404 errors.

Comment: SOLVED....I had it as .jpg...but it was .jpeg.....so i thought those were technically the same but oh well i've got it...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images don't exist:

http://www.saucysbulldogs.com/images/studs/boss/thumbnails/boss4.jpg

Going directly to the image will give you a 404.

Comment: but this happens with local disk too...like straigh from computer (not site) what you see there is exactly what I saw before uploading...i just wanted to see if uploading fixed it..but it didn't

Comment: @Carine Those URLS are relative, not absolute, which means it will try to fetch them from the server, therefore they **need** to be on the server for you to get them. If you want to access local files, you need the full local URL (and some browsers block local files from being shown).

Answer (score 0):

The images images/studs/boss/thumbnails/boss4.jpg and boss5.jpg were not uploaded, my browser can't access them...

Comment: lookup the permissions you have on the images... chmod them to 777 on linux if necessary or in windows set read permission...